# Sort by Formula (without VBA)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to sort a short column of values *(descending)* by using a formula in a different column.  So if **A1** through **A10** contain numbers, in **B1** I enter:

```
=LARGE($A$1:$A$10,ROWS($1:1))
```

and copy down:

[image]

As you see, this is the formula equivalent to copying column **A** to column **B** and then sorting **B** using Sort from the Ribbon.

If the values in column **A** are Text, I can do the same thing by using:

```
=LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(ROWS($1:1),COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,">="&$A$1:$A$10)),$A$1:$A$10)
```

and copying down:

[image]

My problem is devising a formula that will handle both text and numbers.  Here is an example of data in **A** and expected results in **B**:

```
10      zeta
alpha   gamma
zeta    beta
alpha   alpha
2       alpha
beta    10
1       4
gamma   4
4       2
4       1
```

This is easy with *VBA*, but I need a solution with worksheet formulas only.

Comment: Why you don't use the Sort from the Ribbon descending it will do it

Comment: @SuperSam  I am trying to get a formula to sort exactly like Sort from the Ribbon sorts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires that the results start in at least the second row, only because I need a row above for the COUNT() function.

Also it is an array formula:

```
=IF(LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(ROWS($1:1),COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,">="&IF(NOT(ISNUMBER($A$1:$A$10)),$A$1:$A$10))),$A$1:$A$10)<>0,LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(ROWS($1:1),COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,">="&IF(NOT(ISNUMBER($A$1:$A$10)),$A$1:$A$10))),$A$1:$A$10),LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER($A$1:$A$10),$A$1:$A$10),COUNT($C$1:$C1)+1))
```

Being an Array use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then excel will put `{}` around the formula

How it works:

We took the formula to sort text and made it only find the non numeric data `LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(ROWS($1:1),COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,">="&IF(NOT(ISNUMBER($A$1:$A$10)),$A$1:$A$10))),$A$1:$A$10)`  That is done in the COUNTIF with the IF() statment.

This will return 0 after sorting all the non numeric number, so when it equals 0 we use the LARGE() Function only on the number data. `LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER($A$1:$A$10),$A$1:$A$10),COUNT($C$1:$C1)+1)`.

Since COUNT() will only count number we use that as our k in the LARGE().  We count all the numbers above the current cell and add 1 to get the proper k.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! ...................truly beautiful.................once again I must bow to the array formula!

Answer (score 1):

Can you add an aid column, which modify the number values of column A?

If you use the formula

```
=TEXT(A1,"'0")
```

then your slightly modified second formula will work

```
=LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(ROWS($1:4),COUNTIF($B$1:$B$10,">="&$B$1:$B$10)),$A$1:$A$10)
```

[image]

Comment: This works for this small test but put in 11 and it will put it after the 2.

Comment: Thanks! ...................A very interesting idea!  I am going to temporarily use `=CHAR(1) & A1` ................I will mark this as Answer if no direct formulas are posted............Thanks!